# How To Dynamically Create Elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I am struggling to dynamically create  tags for each Subheading (h2 element) I have in my blog, and then fill those  tags with the text of the Subheading.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<script>

            const subheadings = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
            subheadings.forEach(function(x) {
              document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML=x;
              <a href='#' id="contents"></a>
            });
              
</script>
```

This resulted in nothing appearing.

Any help or advice in which direction to look is greatly appreciated.

*** EDIT ***

I have updated the code to an answer that was given in the responses.

```
<div class="col-3" id="contents-table">
          <script>

            const subheading = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
            subheading.forEach(function(x) {              
              let xbe = x.innerText.split(' ');
              for (let i = 0; i<xbe.length;i++) {
              const div = document.getElementById('contents-table');
              let a = document.createElement('a');
              a.innerText = xbe[i];
              console.log( a.innerText); 
              div.append(a);
              }
                });
              
          </script>
        </div>
```

Hopefully, this gives all of the necessary information.

It however still doesn't display the text of the h2 elements but I think the logic is correct.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to do? And share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<h2>
    test example two!
  test example two!
  test example two!
</h2>
<div class="container"></div>
```

css:

```
.holder {
 
  width:1200px;
  height:20px;
  display: flex;
}
```

js:

```
const subheading = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const cont = document.querySelector('.container')
 subheading.forEach(function(x) {  
   cont.innerHTML = ''
   let xbe = x.innerText.split(' ');
   for (let i = 0; i<xbe.length;i++) {
   const test = document.createElement('div');
     test.classList.add('holder')
     let a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href=''
     a.innerText = xbe[i];
     console.log(a); 
     test.append(a);
     cont.append(test)
  }
   
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand the logic of the code so thank you this really clarifies things.

Comment: it functions as a holder for your iteration of the tags, its not necessary to assign that, you don't have to do that, I would like to organize my code in div when I want to do css that way its much easier! glad I can help!!!

Comment: Thanks Hank, it still does not display but I think your logic is correct. Is there some more code I should present to help people fully understand my question?

Comment: I have edited the code to show you